# Mac Terminal Promote User to admin group while User

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, admin, macos-catalina

How do I promote UserB to be an admin while I am logged in as that user?

I have tried:

```
Machine:~ UserB$ su UserAdmin /usr/bin/dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership UserB                                                       
Password: UserAdminsPassword                                                                                                                                                     
/usr/bin/dscl:6: parse error near `)'                                                                                                                          
Machine:~ UserB$
```

I have also tried a ton of other things with other quotes or prens or creating a bash script and calling.

This is on a Mac running Catalina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
su UserAdmin -c 'sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership UserB'
```

If your UserAdmin has a normal admin account it is not allowed to use dscl directly. So after switching to the UserAmin account with `su UserAdmin` another sudo is required for that UserAdmin to call dscl as root.

In your example there is also a `-c` missing as the rest of the command line is a command to execute and not additional arguments for the shell of the user you are switching to.